# Finding words that start and end with same letter

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Why does this code run too slow?

```
SameStartEndWords[char_String] := 
 Table[If[{First[Characters[WordList[][[i]]]]} == Characters[char] && 
 {Last[Characters[WordList[][[i]]]]} == Characters[char], WordList[][[i]], ## &[]], {i, 
 Length[WordList[]]}
```

I am trying to create a list of words from WordList[] that start and end with a specified letter "char". How could I make this more efficent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you said that the start/end character was specified, you could do this:

```
StringBookendedQ[char_] := StringMatchQ[char ~~ ___ ~~ char]
```

and then this:

```
Select[WordList[], StringBookendedQ["a"]]
```

Example with timing:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Select[WordList[], StringBookendedQ["a"]]] // Short
(* {0.076768,{abracadabra,abscissa,acacia,academia,<<45>>,aura,aurora,azalea}} *)
```

**EDIT WITH SOME EXPLANATIONS**

Let's reduce the scope of your original attempt so that we don't have to wait forever (note table range is just 100):

```
SameStartEndWords[char_String] := 
  Table[
    If[
      {First[Characters[WordList[][[i]]]]} == Characters[char] && {Last[Characters[WordList[][[i]]]]} == Characters[char], 
      WordList[][[i]], 
      ## &[]], 
    {i, 100}]
```

Here's a benchmark:

```
AbsoluteTiming[SameStartEndWords["a"]] // Short
(* {3.48274, {"a", "abracadabra"}} *)
```

Now, one thing that's typically worth trying to improve performance is to avoid recalculating things. In your case, you're calculating WordList[] three times per iteration. Let's do it just once:

```
SameStartEndWords2[char_String] :=
  With[
    {words = WordList[]},
    Table[
      If[{First[Characters[words[[i]]]]} == Characters[char] && {Last[Characters[words[[i]]]]} == Characters[char], 
        words[[i]], 
        ## &[]], 
      {i, 100}]]
```

And this gives:

```
AbsoluteTiming[SameStartEndWords2["a"]] // Short
(* {0.019455, {"a", "abracadabra"}} *)
```

This might already be sufficient for your needs. The next step would be to use built-in functions rather than try to "roll your own". There are a host of built-in functions for filtering lists: Select, Cases, Pick, DeleteCases, DeleteDuplicates*. And there are related functions like GroupBy and GatherBy. So, building a table with an If will probably be less performant than the built-in functions.

**EDIT TO DEMONSTRATE ALTERED PROBLEM STATEMENT**

If the requirement were to find all "bookended" strings in WordList[] and group them by initial/terminal letter, you could do this (just adding to the definition of `StringBookendedQ` slightly):

```
StringBookendedQ[] = StringMatchQ[a_ ~~ ___ ~~ a_]
```

With timing:

```
Short[
  AbsoluteTiming[
    GroupBy[
      Select[WordList[], StringBookendedQ[]], 
      StringTake[#, 1] &]], 
  2]
(* {0.078587, <|"a" -> {"abracadabra", "abscissa", "acacia", "academia", 
"acrophobia", <<43>>, "ataxia", "aura", "aurora", 
"azalea"}, <<19>>, "y" -> {<<1>>}|>} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. The advice on recalculating things was also very useful for someone that is learning to code like me!

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Pick[WordList[], StringMatchQ[WordList[], x_ ~~ ___ ~~ x_]];
]

(* {0.040667, Null} *)
```

```
SeedRandom[3];
RandomSample[res, 12]

(* {"needlewoman", "dead", "disregarded", "gesticulating", \
"devoid", "cytotoxic", "noblewoman", "depicted", "trivet", \
"electroplate", "throughput", "disillusioned"} *)
```

Then we can define `SameStartEndWords` in this way:

```
Clear[SameStartEndWords];
SameStartEndWords[] := SameStartEndWords[] = Pick[WordList[], StringMatchQ[WordList[], x_ ~~ ___ ~~ x_]];
SameStartEndWords[char_String] := Pick[SameStartEndWords[], StringMatchQ[SameStartEndWords[], char ~~ __]];
SameStartEndWords[words : {_String ..}, char_String] := Pick[words, StringMatchQ[words, x_ ~~ ___ ~~ x_ /; x == char]];
```

Seems fast:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Association@Table[c -> SameStartEndWords[c], {c, {"a", "m", "v"}}]
]

(* {0.001527, <|"a" -> {"abracadabra", "abscissa", "acacia", 
    "academia", "acrophobia", "agenda", "agoraphobia", "aha", 
    "alfalfa", "alga", "algebra", "alleluia", "aloha", "alpaca", 
    "alpha", "alumina", "alumna", "ambrosia", "ammonia", "amnesia", 
    "amoeba", "amphora", "anaconda", "analgesia", "anaphora", 
    "anathema", "anemia", "anesthesia", "angelica", "angina", 
    "angostura", "anorexia", "antenna", "aorta", "aphasia", "apnea", 
    "apologia", "aqua", "area", "arena", "aria", "armada", "aroma", 
    "arrhythmia", "arugula", "asphyxia", "aspidistra", "asthma", 
    "ataxia", "aura", "aurora", "azalea"}, 
  "m" -> {"ma'am", "macadam", "macrocosm", "madam", "maelstrom", 
    "magnesium", "magnetism", "magnum", "maim", "mainstream", 
    "malapropism", "mammogram", "mannerism", "marjoram", "martyrdom", 
    "materialism", "mausoleum", "maxim", "maximum", "mayhem", 
    "mechanism", "medium", "meerschaum", "memorandum", "mendelevium", 
    "mercantilism", "mesmerism", "metabolism", "metamorphism", 
    "microcosm", "microfilm", "microorganism", "midstream", "midterm",
     "militarism", "millennium", "milligram", "minim", "minimalism", 
    "minimum", "misinform", "modem", "modernism", "modicum", 
    "molybdenum", "mom", "momentum", "monarchism", "monasticism", 
    "monetarism", "mongolism", "monism", "monogram", "monotheism", 
    "moonbeam", "moratorium", "multiculturalism", "multiform", "mum", 
    "museum", "mushroom", "mysticism"}, "v" -> {}|>} *)
```

---

The solution above seems to be twice faster than the [`StringBookendedQ` solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267700/34008):

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res2All = 
   Association@
    Table[
     c -> SameStartEndWords[WordList[], c], {c, 
      CharacterRange["a", "z"]}];
 ]

(* {0.534492, Null} *)
```

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res3All = 
   Association@
    Table[
     c -> Select[WordList[], StringBookendedQ[c]], {c, 
      CharacterRange["a", "z"]}];
 ]

(* {0.909891, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
SameStartEndWords[s_String] := Map[If[First[Characters[#]] === Last[Characters[#]] === s, #, Nothing] &, WordList["KnownWords", Language -> "English"]]
```

Test:

```
SameStartEndWords["c"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using Reap/Sow:

```
Reap[
    Scan[
     If [Equal @@ StringSplit[#, ""][[{1, -1}]], Sow[#]] &, # &@
      WordList[]]
    ][[2, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming // Short[#, 4] &
```

$$\{0.25456,\{\text{a},\text{abracadabra},\text{abscissa},\text{acacia},\text{academia},\text{acrophobia},\text{agenda},\text{agoraphobia},\text{aha},\text{alfalfa},\text{alga},\text{algebra},\text{alleluia},\text{aloha},\langle\langle 1777\rangle\rangle ,\text{window},\text{winnow},\text{withdraw},\text{wow},\text{xerox},\text{yearly},\text{yearningly},\text{yeasty},\text{yeomanry},\text{yesterday},\text{youthfully},\text{yucky},\text{yummy}\}\}$$